# Lateral Creative Question

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Mary, Bill, and John are standing side by side in a straight line. Mary is to the right of Bill; John is to the right of Mary. So is Bill to the left of John? No. Quite the contrary, Bill is to the right of John. How can that be?

Answer (score 13):

Obviously:

> John is facing the opposite direction to Bill and Mary.

Answer (score 8):

> They could be standing in a straight line, on an appropriately-sized sphere.

Answer (score 6):

An additional answer:

> Bill could be to the *political* right - i.e more conservative - and John to the political left (more liberal).

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing the obvious:

> Either the first or the last in line, whoever that may be, is facing the opposite direction of the other two.